# want a Stop FileSystemWatcher() after certain period of time in C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have one requirement in my C# project. I have to scan a files only for certain period of time and it will stop scanning after some hours. For continuous watching a file, I used `FileSystemWatcher()` class and this class continuous will watch a files if any files renamed, created, deleted. Now, my requirement is stop a scanning files after some time. I started a `StartWatcher()` method to start a `FileSystemWatcher()` class. I got a time in sec. How will I call `stopWatcher()` method after certain period of time.

Any quick idea ??

```
m_monitor.StartWatcher();

// code in C# so that I can call StopWatcher after some period of time.

m_monitor.StopWatcher();
```

Comment: Use Timer class. There is a good example on: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Comment: Use a timer, that ticks every second, count the ticks till x seconds passed and then call m_monitor.StopWatcher();

Comment: Janes, in that case you can just tell the timer to wait x seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to solve this. An easy way to do it is with a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
private Timer myTimer = null;
public void YourMethod()
{
  m_monitor.StartWatcher();
  myTimer = new Timer(60000); // 60 seconds
  myTimer.AutoReset = false; // only trigger once
  myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
  myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{
  m_monitor.StopWatcher();
}
```

Haven't tested it but this should push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Delay of the TPL ([Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)).

```
public async Task StartFileSystemWatcher()
        {
            m_monitor.StartWatcher();
            await Task.Delay(Timeout);
            m_monitor.StopWatcher();
        }
```

Comment: An explanation (or link to an explanation) of what TPL is would be nice...