# Run another piece of code after stopping FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, encryption, filesystemwatcher

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` code in C#, which detects files that have changed their content and it then copies these files to a specified directory (C:\Users\wost\Desktop\Data\files). After copying the files, so after `FileSystemWatcher` has stopped, I want to encrypt these files and I want to do this in the same program.
So I have the following code in the main program:

```
Watcher w = new Watcher(lexpt, fexpt, userName);
w.Watch();
// Function which encrypts the files
Encryption.EncryptFiles(@"C:\Users\wost\Desktop\Data\files");
```

This doesn't work because the `FileSystemWatcher` will never stop, only if I quit the program. So, I decided to use a global variable `Global.serviceRunning` like shown in the code below, which stops `FileSystemWatcher` from watching in the specified directory:

```
public void Watch()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    using (watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(
        $"C:\\Users\\wost\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3", _ext))
    {

        // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
        // the renaming of files or directories.
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        // Only watch text files.
        // watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //GLOBAL VARIABLE
        while (Global.serviceRunning == true) ;
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the value of this global variable to `false` in the main program, but it is not working. Can you please help me to find a way how to stop `FileSystemWatcher`, and then encrypt the files within the given directory?

Comment: _"the FileWatcher will never stop, only if I quit the program"_ -- huh? Why don't you just set `EnableRaisingEvents` back to `false`? Alternatively, if you don't want to use the `FileSystemWatcher` object again after it's been disabled, just call its `Dispose()` method. For sure, code like `while (Global.serviceRunning == true) ;` should **NEVER** be used; that's going to tie up a whole CPU core for no useful purpose. But it's not at all clear why you aren't just using the documented, normal mechanism for controlling the `FileSystemWatcher` object.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for your answer! It is the first time for me using FileSystemWatcher and I don't understand very well how it works.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Can you please tell me where do I need to set EnableRaisingEvents  to false, is it in the main program or inside the method Watch() ? Thank you!

Comment: _"where do I need to set EnableRaisingEvents to false"_ -- you need to set it at the point in the execution of your code where you know you no longer need to watch the file system events. You failed to explain that aspect of your scenario in your post, so there's no way to point you to the exact place in the code. I doubt it should go in the `Watch()` method though. More likely, in an event handler where you know you've seen whatever it was you were waiting to see and can disable the `FileSystemWatcher` object.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am sorry about that. I thought it was clear. I don't want to stop FileSystemWatcher at a specified moment. I just want to stop it after a certain amount of time so I can give it enough to look for changes. Can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [want a Stop FileSystemWatcher() after certain period of time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277370/want-a-stop-filesystemwatcher-after-certain-period-of-time-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You're still not being clear. There are two elements to _"stop it after a certain amount of time"_. **Stop it** and **after a certain amount of time**. The former is addressed simply by setting the `EnableRaisingEvents` property. The latter is addressed by the duplicate Q&A [I've proposed above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167726/run-another-piece-of-code-after-stopping-filesystemwatcher?noredirect=1#comment120480055_68167726).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I tried the suggestion from the other question but it didn't work for me. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cancel the related events to stop the FileSystemWatcher.

Code:

```
 static void Stop()
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            watcher.Changed -=new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed -= new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
            watcher.Dispose();
        }
```

I tested in the console app.

Full code:

```
class Program
    {
        static FileSystemWatcher watcher= new FileSystemWatcher();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            watcher.Path = "E:\\Example";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                   NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Press\'q\' to stop the watcher.");
            while (Console.ReadLine()=="q")
            {
                Stop();
            };


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Stop()
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

            watcher.Changed -=new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
          
            watcher.Deleted -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed -= new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
            watcher.Dispose();
        }
        public static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("file:" + e.FullPath + "" + e.ChangeType);
        }
        public static void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fi]e:{0} renamed to{1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167726/run-another-piece-of-code-after-stopping-filewatcher#comment120479045_68167726), the [`FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents) property is the mechanism that you should use in order to activate or deactivate the monitoring of the target directory by the `FileSystemWatcher` component.

Be aware that although the `FileSystemWatcher` events are raised on the `ThreadPool`, an internal mechanism makes it impossible for a handler to be invoked after the deactivation of the component. But any already running handlers are not going to be aborted when you set the `EnableRaisingEvents` to `false`. So you should take into consideration that it is possible for some files to continue being copied in the background, after the moment of the monitoring deactivation.